# Shapes overlapping when Collision AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am new to `AndEngine`. I have three rectangles on a screen. I have set `onAreaTouched` on these rectangles.

when Moving one of these rectangles if they collide they are overlapping with each other.

```
this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

            if (rect1.collidesWith(rect2)
                    || rect1.collidesWith(rect3)) {
                // rect1 should not move further 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

I don't want to overlap them I want if rect1 collide with rect2 then rect1 should not move further.

Comment: Reverse the speed (of the moving object) when collision is occurred?

Comment: I am moving the rectangle with finger. Can you tell me how? any example?

Comment: You must be updating the position according to your finger somewhere right? Just disable that update if this collision is occurred.

Comment: Yes But when disable update, if I move the rect1 on opposite side of other rect then it should be movable. Can you tell me when I should register again updating if I try to move it in opposite side.

Comment: Why would make another registerUpdateHandler? Just enable the update again if there is no collision occurred. Just make an else statement below your current if.

Comment: Ok .I have tried `if (rect1.collidesWith(rect2)
      || rect1.collidesWith(rect3)) {
     mScene.unregisterTouchArea(rect1);
    } else {
     mScene.registerTouchArea(rect1);
    }` but not working.

Comment: If you unregister the touch area it won't detect any new additional movements anymore.  So if you go past the rect nothing will happen. You must have some locationX and Y variables that are being changed by your touch. You have to disable those changes with a boolean or something.

Answer (score 0):

try below code, i think it helpful you.

```
this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

        if (isMoveTouch && (rect1.collidesWith(rect2)
                || rect1.collidesWith(rect3))) {
              isMoveTouch=false
            // rect1 should not move further 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});

@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove() && isMoveTouch) {
        // rect1 movement code
        return true;
    }
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
        isMoveTouch = true;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```